# Python program ends even if the condition are not met

Tags: python, python-3.x

The condition is that the program will end:
-if the balance is less than or equal to zero.
-if the balance is greather than or equal to 200.

But the problem is that it ends after I input 1 or 2 (1 for heads and 2 for tails) and you need to run it again and the balance is not saved.

Here is my code:

```
import random
 
def Guess_Check(guess,balance): #function for guess check
    coin_flip = int( random.choice([1,2]))
    if coin_flip == 1:
        print("It's heads!!")
    else:
        print("It's tail!")
    if guess == coin_flip: #if guess is correct
        print("Congrats you guessed right, You won $9.")
        balance = balance+9
    else: #if guess is wrong
        print("Sorry your guess was wrong, You loss $10.")
        balance = balance-10
    print("Avalilable balanace is :", balance)
    return (balance)
 
def Balance_Check(Balance): #Balance Check
    if Balance <= 10: #we can't play the game if balance is below $10
        print("Sorry!! You run out of money.")
    return(1)
    if Balance >=200:
        print("Congrats!! You reached your Target $200.")
    return(1)
 
balance = 100 #beginning amount
while True:
    bal = Balance_Check(balance) #check the available balance
    if bal==1:
        break
print("Guess heads by entering 1 or tails by entering 2 for this coin flip.") #Asking the player to guess
guess = int(input())
Balance = Guess_Check(guess,balance)
```

Comment: What is `if bal==1 and 200` supposed to mean?

Comment: Shouldn't you be running `Guess_Check()` first and `Balance_Check()` later?

Comment: `bal` is the return value of `Balance_Check`, which always returns 1. So `bal==1` is always true when you check it.

Comment: Also whats the point of Balance_Check() it will always execute once and always return 1 meaning the while loop in the main part always does one iteration meaning its redundant.

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, that is my mistake because I was testing that method I while ago and I did erased it. I modified my post to my latest code where I got stuck. The if bal == 1 is a condition I created to break the while loop. I am not really sure about it.

Comment: Also, ig you need to check the balance in `Balance_Check()` with the variable `Balance` and not `balance`.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Okay, i'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up a few of the things like which balance to take at the right time when to stop the loop etc.

### Here's the code if you want to take the user input once and then check the guess:

```
import random

def Guess_Check(guess,balance): #function for guess check
    coin_flip = random.choice([1,2])
    if coin_flip == 1:
        print("It's heads!!")
    else:
        print("It's tail!")
    if guess == coin_flip: #if guess is correct
        print("Congrats you guessed right, You won $9.")
        balance = balance+9
    else: #if guess is wrong
        print("Sorry your guess was wrong, You loss $10.")
        balance = balance-10
    print("Avalilable balanace is :", balance)
    return (balance)

def Balance_Check(Balance): #Balance Check
    if Balance <= 10: #we can't play the game if balance is below $10
        print("Sorry!! You run out of money.")
        return 0
    elif Balance >=200:
        print("Congrats!! You reached your Target $200.")
        return 1

balance = 100 #beginning amount

print("Guess heads by entering 1 or tails by entering 2 for this coin flip.") #Asking the player to guess
guess = int(input())
while Balance_Check(balance) not in [0,1]: # You need to run the loop till balance becomes 0 or 200
    balance = Guess_Check(guess,balance)
```

### But if you want to take user input on every chance use:

```
import random

def Guess_Check(guess,balance): #function for guess check
    coin_flip = random.choice([1,2])
    if coin_flip == 1:
        print("It's heads!!")
    else:
        print("It's tail!")
    if guess == coin_flip: #if guess is correct
        print("Congrats you guessed right, You won $9.")
        balance = balance+9
    else: #if guess is wrong
        print("Sorry your guess was wrong, You loss $10.")
        balance = balance-10
    print("Avalilable balanace is :", balance)
    return (balance)

def Balance_Check(Balance): #Balance Check
    if Balance <= 10: #we can't play the game if balance is below $10
        print("Sorry!! You run out of money.")
        return 0
    elif Balance >=200:
        print("Congrats!! You reached your Target $200.")
        return 1

balance = 100 #beginning amount


while Balance_Check(balance) not in [0,1]: # You need to run the loop till balance becomes 0 or 200
    guess = int(input("Guess heads by entering 1 or tails by entering 2 for this coin flip."))
    balance = Guess_Check(guess,balance)
```

Sample output: (Not complete output as it was long)

```
Congrats you guessed right, You won $9.
Avalilable balanace is : 206
Congrats!! You reached your Target $200.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry that I cannot upvote your answer because this is a new account. I will review your solution and study it.

Comment: @SanyaSansen If it helped you then you can accept the answer by clicking on tick mark :)